# Test if a user command is at the end of the document

Tags: macros, expl3, hooks, lthooks

Is there any chance for a command `\testcommand` to test if it is the last user command before `\end{document}`? Since there are still hooks at `enddocument`, this seems a little bit tricky.

I am thinking of placing an empty command `\somethingempty` and let `\testcommand` to detect it using `\peek_meaning:N(TF)`. However, if I put it in the hook, the first thing `\testcommand` see would become some sort of `\UseHook`.

*The motivation for this question is that in my package there is some spacing adjustment for a command that should only be done in the middle of the document.*

Below is a MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\def\somethingempty{}
\NewDocumentCommand \testcommand { }
  {
    % \peek_meaning:NF \somethingempty
    \peek_regex:nF { (\ *)? (\c{par}*)? (\ *)? \c{somethingempty} }
      {
        %% Some code that only should happen in the middle of the text
        ``something in the middle of the text''
      }
  }

\AddToHook{enddocument}{\somethingempty}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\testcommand

Text.

\testcommand

% \somethingempty

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you're fine with requiring 2 passes, the obvious solution would be to use the auxiliary file to count how many times the command has been executed and the total number of times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solving this in the general case seems really hard, but “there is some spacing adjustment for a command that should only be done in the middle of the document” suggests that these two restrictions will probably be fine:

1. “some code that only should happen in the middle of the text” typesets only vertical-mode material, and
2. You only need to test for “the last user command *that produces horizontal-mode material* before `\end{document}`”.

If these two restrictions are okay, then you can use a `para/before` hook:

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\pagestyle{empty}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\def\somethingempty{}
\NewDocumentCommand \testcommand { }
  {
    \hook_gput_next_code:nn { para/before } {
        \vskip 1ex \relax
        \hrule width \textwidth height 1pt depth 0pt \relax
        \vskip 1ex \relax
    }
  }

\AddToHook{enddocument}{\somethingempty}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\testcommand

Text.

\testcommand

Text.

\testcommand

\somethingempty

\end{document}
```

[image: sample output]